# CKAN Imapper plugin appears to do nothing

Tags: ckan

CKAN's documentation looks quite clear on how one should gain access to models before/after database operations:

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IMapper

Based on that I've created a plugin which does stuff like this, amongst other things:

```
import ckan.plugins as plugins

class MyPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IMapper)

    def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        print("INSERTING: %r", instance)
        log("INSERTING: %r", instance)
        raise ValueError("FRC!") # Just in case it's a logging/printing problem
```

Although I am certain that the plugin is installed, for other functions it provides behave as they should, the before_insert or any other call I make never logs anything or raises the exception. Presumably, therefore, it is not being called and either the documentation is wrong/incomplete or I've completely misunderstood it.

I've asked about this on the CKAN list but with no result - can anyone here suggest what the problem might be?